# Web scraping when goes to 403 page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner at web scraping and am required to scrape https://mirror-h.org/archive/page/1 using Beautifulsoup. But it is giving an error and goes to the 403 page. How can I solve this? I really appreciate your help.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

url = "https://mirror-h.org/archive/page/1"
page = pandas.read_html(url)
headers = {
    'user-agent:' 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'
    }
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

The error I get is:

```
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Hi Tharika, HTTP Error code 403 means that you dont have access to this page. There can be numerous reasons. for example the page might have some sort of WAF infront that does not allow "bot" request to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# make sure you insert the headers as a dict as you missed the : within your original code
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
}


def main(url):
    # included headers in request
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    # response 200
    print(r)


    # this is how you can use pandas with the previous headers to get 200 response text
    df = pd.read_html(r.text)
    print(df)  # you will get error --> ValueError: No tables found because you are dealing with JS website behind CloudFlare protection! try selenium then!
    


main('https://mirror-h.org/archive/page/1 ')
```